# Stability simulation - breaking the loop for a MOSFET - op-amp current source

Tags: operational-amplifier, mosfet, current-source, stability, inductive

The task at hand is to create a voltage controlled current source of 60 mA driving a valve coil (64 mH, 139 Ω). I am aware the MOSFET used is insufficient powerwise; it was a quick attempt to have a low-capacitance one.

When I run transient analyses for two different op-amps, the behaviour looks fine and stable, the coil current is just a straight line at 62 mA.

[image]

[image]

However, I tried to check stability by breaking the loop as described in *[Negative Feedback, Part 9: Breaking the Loop](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/negative-feedback-part-9-breaking-the-loop/)*.

When I do this for the AD8541, I get this:

[image]

[image]

And when I use te LTC6240, I get this:

[image]

[image]

Why is the transient analysis for the AD8541 (and for the LTC6240 too) completely stable, but does the broken loop AC analysis seem very unstable (-90°)?

What puzzles me most is the LTC6240 version; what does it mean when the phase goes from +90° at low frequencies to around +260° between the resonances and then shoots up to over 400°?

What causes the resonances? For the LTC6240 they are at 30 kHz and 165 kHz and for thr AD8541 at 38 kHz and 165 kHz. If it is the 64 mH resonanting, the corresponding capacitance is 14 pF, which could be the output capacitance of the MOSFET. But 30 kHz with the same coil corresponds to 440 pF; where is it?

It looks like the coil plays havoc with stability. Are their any special tricks here, or is standard in-loop compensation suitable?

Comment: You have all the tools to hand to prove it's the inductor by running an analysis with it shorted out.

Comment: "*Why is the transient analysis [...] completely stable*" & "*the behaviour looks fine and stable, the coil current is just a straight line at 62mA*" -- have you tried stepping your reference? E.g. don't just leave it as a fixed voltage, add some variations, preferably stepped.

Comment: @Andy aka Yes, with the inductor shorted out magnitude and phase drop, phase margin is 64° for the AD8541 and 22° for the LTC6240. I guess for the AD8541 the 1st resonance makes the circuit go towards instability with phase going abruptly from +90° to -90°, then the 2nd resonance makes the circuit go towards stability again with phase going abruptly back from -90° to +90°. But the LTC6240 is strange: going from +90° to 260° (260° equivalent to -100°, so unstable?) and then from +260° to 440° (440° equivalent to +80°, so stable?). Maybe degrees beyond +/- 180° are an LTspice thing, not physical